# Subscribe to content type creation event

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I'm using Drupal 8 (8.6.2). My main objective is to read fields of newly created content type (or changed, it doesn't matter) and create few helper data structures. To achieve this, I'm trying to somehow subscribe to an appropriate event. Unfortunately - no luck. Currently I have:

test_api.services.yml:

```
services:
    test_api_type.listener:
        class: '\Drupal\test_api\BundleEventsListener'
        tags:
            - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

And BundleEventsListener.php:

```
<?php

namespace \Drupal\test_api;

use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBundleListener;
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeListener;
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeEvents;
use \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeEventSubscriberTrait;

class BundleEventsListener extends EntityTypeListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    use EntityTypeEventSubscriberTrait;
    public function __construct() {
            \Drupal::logger('test_api_mod')->notice('BUNDLE EVENT LISTENER CREATED');
    }
    public function onEntityTypeCreate($ent) {
            \Drupal::logger('test_api_mod')->notice('ON ENTITY TYPE CREATE');
    }
    public function onEntityTypeUpdate($lhs, $rhs) {
            \Drupal::logger('test_api_mod')->notice('ON ENTITY TYPE UPDATE');
    }
    public function onEntityTypeDelete($ent) {
            \Drupal::logger('test_api_mod')->notice('ON ENTITY TYPE DELETE');
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
            return static::getEntityTypeEvents();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this setup does not work - at all. This class isn't even instantiated - though I don't really know at what point it should happen. This seems to follow nearly line in line code from Drupal\views\EventSubscriber\ViewsEntitySchemaSubscriber class, but it simply does not work. I tried to implemented module [described here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/event-systems-overview-how-to-subscribe-to-and-dispatch-events) and it simply works.

I am out of ideas at this point. Is this method supported? It should, this code is from Drupal's code. But maybe I'm subscribing to something different? But in this case - what is EntityType?

Also is there any documentation regarding split described [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2549139)? It seems that I could listen to bundle creation and it would be fine, but there is no event type for this.

I'm completely lost, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, one could "subscribe" to them using [hook_entity_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x)

Comment: Is the YAML indentation correct? Have you debugged it further?

Comment: Kevin, yaml is fine afaict, it seems it is read and getSubscribedEvents is called - I have added logging statement there and got errors about uninitialized logger, albeit from "drush cr" command.

Comment: Ok, so I modified Drupal class Drupal\views\EventSubscriber\ViewsEntitySchemaSubscriber so that it logs information whenever it is called. It is either never called (on creation, modification and deletion of content type, field, comment, view or form) or these logs are not in fact written to the log. Other logs written in the same way show without problems in the logs. I changed logging statements to exceptions and STILL nothing works. I'm surprised as this file seems to be pretty important - it is also only one that has anything to do with EntityTypeEvents.